# refactoring from Spray to Akka http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, spray

I have a Spray RestClient and I have to rewrite it to Akka HTTP, but I never use both of these frameworks before. Can you send some references, literature or examples which can help me?

Comment: There are Host level, connection level, request level API's that akka supports.
Take a look at this
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/request-level.html

Answer (score 0):

`Akka-http` is based on `spray` so syntax is quite similar.

More info available here:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/migration-guide/migration-from-spray.html
https://jobs.zalando.com/tech/blog/migrating-spray-akka-http/?gh_src=4n3gxh1
http://queirozf.com/entries/migrating-a-project-from-spray-to-akka-http-general-tips-and-reference